# How to get Redshift error in my local error log file?

Tags: python, sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to load a bulk data from my python code from an API to my Data Warehouse. The libraries I am using specific to this is Boto and psycopg2. After the data/ files loaded to S3, I am firing a SQL script to copy the data from S3 to amazon redshift.

Now, the point is if there is any error, my python code will exit with state 1. Each time I need to go to check the STL_LOAD_ERRORS Table to check the error.
I want to pull that inside a variable of my code and write it down to the log file.

Please let me know if that is possible and if it is possible, how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty general but will give you what you need

```
import psycopg2
import logging

# connect to database somewhere up here

data_q = """
         COPY COMMAND
         """

error_q = """
          SELECT filename, err_reason FROM
          STL_LOAD_ERRORS 
          ORDER BY starttime DESC LIMIT 1;
          """

def main():
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        try:
            cursor.execute(data_q)
        except psycopg2.Error as e:
            cursor.execute(error_q)
            err = cursor.fetchone()
            logging.error('{} failed to upload due to {}'.format(*err))
            conn.rollback()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your post.. I think this is perfect. I didn't knew it. I will definitely try this in my code. Thanks again. :)